# Mass-energy equation and Einstein field equations

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mass-energy

I don't know much about Einstein field equations, but I'm wondering are there any relationships between the Einstein field equation (or the vacuum field equation) and the Mass-Energy equation $E=mc^2$? Or they are describing different objects so should be considered separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special relativity only tells us $E=mc^2$, and a more general account of four-momentum (momentum and energy). The Einstein field equation from general relativity tells us how spacetime geometry responds to the distribution of mass, momentum and energy, and hence to how mass-energy already works in special relativity.